# Slow and unresponsive activity in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, optimization

I have a simple activity that needs to be active for 10-15 minutes. The activity is using TelephonyManager to get three LTE parameters: RSRP, RSRQ, PCI. It collects these three parameters and a timestamp once per second, and therefore, the UI gets updated once per second.

The method used to get the LTE parameters is run on a background thread. Other than the UI getting updated every second, nothing is very computationally intensive. However, if I run the activity for more than five minutes then I get the lovely Android Monitor message:  **"I/Choreographer: Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."**

So I must be doing something wrong because I believed I was doing all the hard work on the background thread. If I run the activity for 10-15 minutes it will skip ~1,000 frames. Then if I go through the app and press the button to run another test it will start off skipping as many frames as it did at the end of the previous 15 minute test and by the end of the second test it can skip as many as 2500 frames. Then it takes longer and longer each time you press a button to start the next activity (even on activities where literally nothing is being done). And there are only five activities!

Here is a screenshot of the activity that I need to have active collecting data for 15 minutes:

[image: screenshot1]

And the corresponding Android Monitor log:
[image: screenshot2]

Here is my code for the activity called Third.java:

```
package com.parksjg.its.pscrindoortesttool;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.CellInfo;
import android.telephony.CellInfoLte;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

/**
 * Created by josephparks on 1/27/16.
 */
public class Third extends Activity implements Runnable {

    SignalStrengthListener signalStrengthListener;
    TextView lteRsrp;
    TextView lteRsrq;
    TextView cellPciTextView, fileName;
    ImageView img;
    Button stopButton;

    TelephonyManager tm;
    List<CellInfo> cellInfoList;
    String lte1, lte2;
    int cellPci = 0;

    ArrayList data;
    CSVWriter writer;
    String mydate;
    String startDate;
    boolean done = false;


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Moves the current Thread into the background
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

        // This runs the code to grab the LTE parameters
        startTele();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third_activity);

        // Sets up the TextViews and UI
        setupUI();
        // Runs telephony method on background thread
        run();
        // takes the collected data and adds it to the CSV format once per second
        setupCSV();
        // Sets up the stop button, writes data to CSV, and starts next activity
        setupButton();

    }

    // This method is called by startTele() and is responsible for grabbing the LTE params 
    private class SignalStrengthListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength signalStrength) {

            ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

            tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            String ltestr = signalStrength.toString();
            String[] parts = ltestr.split(" ");
            lte1 = parts[9];
            lte2 = parts[10];

            try {
                cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
                for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
                    if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                        // cast to CellInfoLte and call all the CellInfoLte methods you need
                        // Gets the LTE PCI: (returns Physical Cell Id 0..503, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                        cellPci = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getPci();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
//                Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 3: " + e);
            }

            // Gets the timestamp of when these LTE params where collected
            mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            // Updates the UI TextViews for RSRP, RSRQ, and PCI
            lteRsrp.setText(String.valueOf(lte1));
            lteRsrq.setText(String.valueOf(lte2));
            cellPciTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellPci));

            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

        }
    }

    // This takes the collected LTE data and timestamps and concatenates them into one object
    // which is then easy to create a CSV file from
    private void setupCSV() {
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                data.add(new String[]{mydate, lte1, lte2, String.valueOf(cellPci)});
            }
        }, 0, 1000);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second

    }

    private void setupUI () {

        data = new ArrayList();

        // startDate is used to name the CSV file
        startDate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        lteRsrp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lteRsrp);
        lteRsrq = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lteRsrq);
        cellPciTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellPciTextView);
        fileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fileName);
        fileName.setText(startDate);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.recording);

//        Log.d("Time and Date", "+++++++++++++ DATE : " + mydate);

    }

    private void startTele() {
        // start the signal strength listener
        signalStrengthListener = new SignalStrengthListener();

        ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try {
            cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
//            Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 1: " + e);

        }

    }

    private void setupButton() {
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(Third.this, "Writing output to CSV!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Writes the data to a CSV file named by startDate
                writeCSV();

                try{
                    if(signalStrengthListener != null) {
                        tm.listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_NONE);
//                        Log.d("TAG", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Stop button Success!!!!!!");
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
//                    Log.d("TAG", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Stop button Fail!!!!!! with error = " + e);
                }

                // Intent passes startDate and the boolean done to indicate when the CSV has been written
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Fourth.class);
                intent.putExtra("START_DATE", startDate);
                intent.putExtra("DONE", done);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

    private void writeCSV() {

        try {
            File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), startDate+".csv");
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file, true), ',');
            // Headers
            String[] headers = "Time, RSRP, RSRQ, PCI".split(",");
            writer.writeNext(headers);
            writer.writeAll(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(Third.this, "CSV Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            done = true;
//                    Log.d("CSV Writer", "CSV Writer Successful!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
//            Log.d("CSV Writer", "Error writing CSV file : " + e);
            Toast.makeText(Third.this, "Error writing CSV file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the corresponding XML called third_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffdc1d">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recording"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/lteRecording"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="#f91616"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE RSRP"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stopButton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#a71b1b"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE RSRQ"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#a71b1b"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#075f09"
        android:id="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE PCI"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#075f09"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#ffdc1d"
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:background="#f91616"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/recording"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Filename:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:id="@+id/fileName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parksjg.its.pscrindoortesttool" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".First"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Second"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="true">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Third"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="true">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Fourth"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="true">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Final"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="true">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Am I putting the wrong code to execute in the background thread? How can I make this run smoother and more responsive? Again, it is fast when run under 5 minutes, but we use this to test research indoor LTE networks and our walk tests/drive tests need to be 10-15 minutes, but when I hit the stop button, or the new test button I need it to respond within a second or two. Sometimes it takes 20-30 seconds for the action to take effect after having pressed the button, particularly after consecutive testing.

Below is the complete flow of the app:

[image: Flow1]

[image: Flow2]

[image: Flow3]

[image: Flow4]

[image: Flow5]

The button from the last activity restarts the second activity. Let me know if you need any other code, I can also post the whole AndroidStudio project on GitHub if anyone is interested in running the code themselves.

Thanks!

Comment: `android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);` This is not how you create a background thread. Use an `AsyncTask` or even create a new `Thread` instead of changing the priority of the activity's thread.

Comment: My understanding was that I created a new thread and I am just setting that threads priority to background. But are you saying that I just changed the activities main thread to background priority?

Comment: The documentation says to use AsyncTask for operations that only last a few seconds. Since I want to do the Telephony listener on a separate thread for 15 minutes, should I use something from the *.concurrent package like `Executor`? Also, is it bad practice to use one AsyncTask for the listener and then another AsyncTask for writing the CSV in the same activity?

Comment: The `AsyncTask` makes it easy to modify the GUI. You can create normal  threads for the operations that don't need to modify the GUI. Also, the listeners will create their own threads.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's something that builds over time it propably  means that Views or objects are not being garbage collected properly by the OS because their references are not being released...which leads to memory problems. I suggest as a first step to use a memory profiler and check how much of your memory is being used over the duration of your test. Other than that you could check the time that your methods need to be executed by doing something like this

```
void methodName(){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    .
    .
    .
    .
    Log.w("time needed for this method",Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
}
```

Comment: I run out of memory in about a minute and a half, then it frees 30% to 40% of the memory but again runs out in about a minute. Is that normal?

Comment: also setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND); does not mean that the thread will be executed in the background. You use AsyncTask or Service to do that