# AsyncTask FATAL EXCEPTION when calling a method from doInBackground

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

None of the answers to questions on this topic have solved the issue for my specific case.

My app is hogging memory and causing the main thread to be unresponsive. I am using a listener to monitor Telephony states. When the state changes (or once per second) I want to grab the parameter associated and update a `TextView` with its value. I have tried using `Threads` and `Runnables` but the performance still sucks. Now I am trying `AsyncTask` but I don't understand it. I want this activity to run for at least 15 minutes with the listener running that whole time in the background; and once per second I want the values grabbed with the listener to be used to update TextViews on the UI thread.

```
public class Second extends Activity {

    SignalStrengthListener signalStrengthListener;
    TextView lteRsrp;
    TextView lteRsrq;
    TextView cellPciTextView;

    Button startButton;

    TelephonyManager tm;
    List<CellInfo> cellInfoList;
    String lte1, lte2;
    int cellPci = 0;
//    List<String[]> data;

//    @Override
//    public void run() {
//        // Moves the current Thread into the background
//        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
//        startTele();
//
//    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        setupUI();
//        run();
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();

        setupButton();

    }


        public class SignalStrengthListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength signalStrength) {

            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

                ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

                tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                String ltestr = signalStrength.toString();
                String[] parts = ltestr.split(" ");
                lte1 = parts[9];
                lte2 = parts[10];

                try {
                    cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
                    for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
                        if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                            // cast to CellInfoLte and call all the CellInfoLte methods you need
                            // Gets the LTE PCI: (returns Physical Cell Id 0..503, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                            cellPci = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getPci();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 3: " + e);
                }

//                lteRsrp.setText(String.valueOf(lte1));
//                lteRsrq.setText(String.valueOf(lte2));
//                cellPciTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellPci));


                super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        }
    }


    private void setupUI() {
        lteRsrp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lteRsrp);
        lteRsrq = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lteRsrq);
        cellPciTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellPciTextView);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

    }


    public void startTele() {

        //start the signal strength listener
        signalStrengthListener = new SignalStrengthListener();

        ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try {
            cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 1: " + e);

        }

    }


    private void setupButton() {
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Third.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    //??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

//        WeakReference<TextView> lteRsrpWRef, lteRsrqWRef, ltePciWRef;

//        public MyAsyncTask(TextView lteRsrp, TextView lteRsrq, TextView cellPciTextView) {
//            lteRsrpWRef = new WeakReference<TextView>(lteRsrp);
//            lteRsrqWRef = new WeakReference<TextView>(lteRsrq);
//            ltePciWRef = new WeakReference<TextView>(cellPciTextView);
//
//        }

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            startTele();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            lteRsrp.setText(String.valueOf(lte1));
            lteRsrq.setText(String.valueOf(lte2));
            cellPciTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellPci));

        }
    }
    //??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

}
```

My attempt to use AsyncTask is at the bottom enclosed by "`//????????????`". I simply want to call `startTele()` which then calls the `SignalStrengthListener` from the `doInBackground()` in AsyncTask so that all that code will be run on a background thread. Then I want to get the values `String lte1`, `String lte2`, and `int cellPci` and use them to update `TextView lteRsrp, lteRsrq, cellPciTextView;` on the UI thread.

Here is my XML for Second.class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffdc1d">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE RSRP"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#a71b1b"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE RSRQ"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#a71b1b"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#075f09"
        android:id="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE PCI"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#075f09"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textColor="#ffdc1d"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:background="#f91616"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press the START button to begin recording"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#f91616"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my logcat messages:

[image]

So, how can I run my telephony listener in the background for 15 minutes while grabbing the LTE parameters RSRP, RSRQ, and PCI and updating the TextViews on the UI thread with these values once per second?

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure so I'm posting it as a comment, but I don't think you can construct a PhoneStateListener on a thread without a looper- it looks like its constructor is looking for a looper.  Try creating it in onPreExecute and using it in doInBackground.  Or just do all this on the main thread-  I'm not sure why you're doing this on a task.

Comment: When I run it on the main thread for 10-15 minutes it slows the UI so when I go to press the button nothing happens for a couple seconds in the best case and as much as 20-30 seconds at worst case. For more context you can read my other question that spawned this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145181/slow-and-unresponsive-activity-in-android . I'll look into looper, never heard of that but I see it now in logcat.

Comment: If you instantiate the PhoneStateListener in onPreExecute, store it in a class variable of the AsyncTask, and then just use it in doInBackground it will probably work ok.